# Drafty windows on sides - how to seal?

Tags: windows, winterizing

I have windows that were poorly installed -- the outer frame isn't square and therefore there are some uneven gaps where a cold draft comes in. I live in New England, so this is a problem for us. I've read about many solutions, such as using foam, but that will be too wide, I think.

I'm posting a photo that shows the gap -- you can see a small gap, about 1/8", to the right of the fuzzy material. Whatever I put in there needs with withstand the rubbing of the window going up and down. I want to find a solution that fills that gap as opposed to using a film over the entire window.

Please let me know if there are products that could solve this draft issue.

[image]

Comment: Is it poorly installed or does it just not close properly because the hinges need replaced?  ( I recently replaced hinges on a window that had a small gap at the top and now it closes perfectly)

Comment: Well the bottom of the frame is wider than the top. There is no gap at the top because the width at the top seems to be the proper width. The bottom gets wider and that's where the gap is. The gap is on both the left and the right. I think it needs to be something that somehow fills the gap.

Comment: Could you edit and add a picture showing the track mechanism with the window rolled up  a bit? It would help to know how much space you have there.

Comment: If u have gaps on the left and right then it does not sound like a simple replacement of the hinges.  But yeah more pictures would be helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get some felt weather stripping, the "fuzzy material". It comes in many thicknesses at your home stores. It has a self adhesive strip that you can fasten to the frame opposite the fuzzy material on the window. So you'll have fuzzy material rubbing against fuzzy material. That should seal the gap and give you a warm and fuzzy feeling... Good luck.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I think that would do it. Thanks!

Comment: Now that you say that, I may also consider replacing the wool pile that's inside my window if I can find one that's the right size and deeper than the OEM one.